# Selenium java. Как выделить конкретный фрагмент из текста?

Tags: java, selenium

После регистрации на сайте, на почту приходят креды в формате:
**логин: example@mail.ru
пароль: password123**

Необходимо выделить и скопировать конкретно логин и пароль, без постороннего текста, для дальнейшей передачи их в инпут. Подскажите пожалуйста, как это можно осуществить?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Например взять строку с текстом письма, и с помощью регулярки выдернуть от туда пароль

```
import java.util.regex.Matcher;
import java.util.regex.Pattern;

public class Program {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        String text = "логин: example@mail.ru пароль: password123 текст";
        Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile("пароль:.* ");
        Matcher matcher = pattern.matcher(text);
        while (matcher.find()) {
            System.out.println(text.substring(matcher.start(), matcher.end()));
        }
    }
}
```